# Bootstrap is not working on wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have installed [Insert Headers and Footers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/) plugin in my WordPress. It works fine but when i add bootstrap to my theme, nothing changes.

I am using [ritz theme](http://justfreethemes.com/demo/?theme=Ritz) for a blog so i added my header and footer to the page using a plugin.

I referenced bootstrap CDN like inside the theme `function.php`

**css bootstrap link**

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' );
```

**bootstrap js link**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js');
```

Any help is higlhy welcome. thanks

Comment: are you adding any bootstrap classes to your markup?

Comment: open your site --> `CTRL` + `U` , check if bootstrap is being added at all !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik it is there. there is this <link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap_css-css'  href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css?ver=4.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />. in page sourse

Comment: @Engxtian if its there in your source and u've applied the bootstrap classes where you need them there is no reason bootstrap should't work , unless u've overridden the css in your own stylesheet. do you have a link that you can share ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

theme `function.php` add this code

```
function hook_bootstrap() {
    ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Bootstrap Basic" theme would install all the Bootstrap core files to your Wordpress website for you, so you don't have to deal with adding any codes your own.

Try go to Appearance -> Themes -> click "Add new" and search for "Bootstrap Basic" and install it to your wordpress website.

If you want to know more about any Boostrap Tips & Tricks, visit https://iiiji.com/bootstrap/.

[Visit to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74nE3.jpg)